# Как получить высоту в inline блоке Fancybox

Tags: jquery, fancybox, height

Подскажите пожалуйста, пытаюсь получить высоту определенного блока в модальном окне Fancybox, но постоянно получаю 0, понимаю что нужно сделать это после загрузки самого модального окна, но как точно сделать не знаю.
Буду благодарен за помощь, спасибо.

Comment: У `display: inline` элемента нет высоты

Comment: inline content fancybox 3 http://prntscr.com/jt02jq внутри такого попап окна в определенном div нужно посчитать высоту, в таком блоке разве нет высоты?